# Paymill successful transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paymill

I'm integrating Paymill in my Rails app. I'm using the 'paymill' gem.
When I make a transaction like this:

```
Paymill::Transaction.create(amount: amount,
                            currency: "BGN",
                            client: client.paymill_id,
                            payment: paymill_id,
                            description: order.code)
```

This will return a transaction object. The transaction object has a response code. The response code is 20000 for a successful transaction.

Is this the only scenario when a transaction will be successful? Is it possible the response code to be different than 20000 and at some later point the transaction to succeed? Do I need to setup webhooks to wait for some event? Do I need to be checking the status of the transaction(open, pending, closed, failed, partial_refunded, refunded, preauthorize, chargeback)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now pending is not supported right now and than has a code like something with 1XXXX. BUT not right now - we will do that later this year.

Till now you'll get only 20000 if ok or 4XXXX/5XXXX for errors (have a look at the response codes https://www.paymill.com/de-de/dokumentation/referenz/api-referenz/#response-codes).

If you need some other codes you want to try than please use one of the creditcardnumbers displayed at the testing page at docu https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/testing/ .

Best,
Christian